# conditions in if statement in C not working while using &&, despite working separately

Tags: c, string, if-statement, c-strings

My if statement has two conditions. The statement is inside  two nested for loops, as follows:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
{
    for(char j = 'a'; j <= 'z'; j++)
    {
        if((strcasecmp(&word[0], &j) == 0) && (strlen(word) == i))
        {
            //code here
        }
    }
}
```

(word is a const char *, length is a constant defined as 45).

If the condition contains only one of these two, it returns true when either of the two conditions are run, so they are both true separately. However, when I put them together like this, it returns false.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Please construct a [mre]

Comment: You can't pass `&j` to `strcasecmp` because it isn't a null-terminated string.  That triggers undefined behavior and from then on who knows what will happen.

Comment: The `if` condition is evaluated in a lazy way such that if your condition is a sequence of "and"s it will return `false` when the first condition evaluates to `false` without evaluating the rest. In similar way if your condition is a sequence of "or"s it will return `true` when the first condition evaluates to `true`.

Comment: The comparison doesn't seem to make a lot of sense anyway.  Even if `&j` were a one-character string, the `strcasecmp` would return nonzero anytime `word` contains more than one character.  `&word[0]` means the same as `word`; it looks like you think you're just comparing the first character, but that's not so.

Comment: I think it'd help if you could give more context, including the surrounding code, and explain what this code is actually meant to accomplish.

Comment: @NateEldredge The program overall is a spell checker, but this part basically has to do with constructing a hash table to store words from a predefined dictionary. The function this is in is meant to be a hash function for a word passed in, and it returns the index of wherever the word is supposed to be.

Comment: @belle What is the purpose of these two loops? What  are you trying to check? The code looks like it does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `strcasecmp` expects a pointer to a null-terminated string for each of its arguments.  The first argument is fine, as it is the same as `word`.  The second however is not because you're passing a pointer to a single character.  The function will attempt to treat it as a string and read past the memory bounds of the single character.  This causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

It looks like you really want to compare a single character to one character in the string in a case insensitive way.  You can use the `tolower` function to convert a single character to lower case to compare against a lower case character, and use that on each element of the string:

```
if (tolower(word[i]) == j)
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been observed in comments, this function call is not sensible:

> ```
> strcasecmp(&word[0], &j) == 0)
> ```

because `&j` is not a pointer to a null-terminated string.  Moreover, if a `word` is a valid pointer to `const char`, then `&word[0]` is needlessly obtuse, as it is equivalent to just `word`.

I intuit that what you are looking for is a case-folded comparison of the first character of `word` with the value of `j`.  Since `j`'s values in this scope are always lowercase ASCII letters, that would be best achieved with this condition, instead:

```
tolower(word[0]) == j
```